# Handling Data Annotation Validation with Custom ValidationResult

Tags: c#, validation, inheritance, attributes, radix

I have a custom ValidationAttribute like this :

```
public class ReceiverRegion : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private RegionService regionService;
        private CityService cityService;

        public ReceiverRegion() : base("Incorrect region code")
        {
            this.regionService = new RegionService();
            this.cityService = new CityService();
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            int regionId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            int plate = Convert.ToInt32((validationContext.ObjectInstance as CorporateOrderItem).ReceiverCity);

            int productGroupId = Convert.ToInt32(validationContext.Items["productGroup"].ToString());

            if (!CheckReceiverRegionExistence(regionId, plate, productGroupId))
            {
                IEnumerable regions = this.regionService.GetList(cityService.GetByPlate(plate).PKCityId);

                return new CorporateOrderValidationResult(base.ErrorMessage, regions.Select(r=>r.Name));
            }
            return CorporateOrderValidationResult.Success;
        }

        private bool CheckReceiverRegionExistence(int plate, int regionId, int productGroup)
        {
            return !(regionService.GetByCityAndRegionIdForProductGroup(plate, regionId, productGroup) == null);
        }
    }
```

But as you can see in IsValid method, I'm trying to return a custom object which inherits from ValidationResult. My problem is, I can't access the extra members of my `CorporateOrderValidationResult` instance since IsValid returns the base ValidationResult type. Below is the code where I call validate and get a collection of ValidationResult as return value.

```
List results = new List();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, context, results, true);
```

I tried to cast results object to `List<CorporateOrderValidationResult>`, but no matter what I try(for instance --> `item as CorporateOrderValidationResult` or `results.OfType<CorporateOrderValidationResult>()` or `(CorporateOrderValidationResult)item)` I either get InvalidCastException or null value. Is there a possible way to convert this list of result to a list of my custom result class? Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce this behavior, but everything works as expected:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [TestValidation]
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
}

public class TestValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new TestResult();
    }
}

public class TestResult : ValidationResult
{
    public TestResult()
        : base("test")
    {
    }
}
```

Code for validation:

```
var instance = new TestClass();
var context = new ValidationContext(instance, null, null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, context, results, true);
//Contains one instance of TestResult
var customResults = results.OfType<TestResult>().ToArray();
```

Comment: The code you tried here looks exact same case with me. But when I called var customResults = results.OfType<TestResult>().ToArray(); no item returned even there were some ValidationResult objects in the collection. I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but first result in Google when you ask for custom `ValidationResult` class. Example presented by Vyacheslav Volkov works, but why?

I spent few hours today trying to make my code working - the key line is:

`public TestResult(): base ("test")`

I was not going to use error message at all, I had my own structure for this so I wrote my ctor like this:

`public TestResult() : base("")` - empty string sent to base class has consequences, that are not mentioned in documentation. `TryValidate()` method will not insert our object into `results` collection as it is returned by our version of `IsValid()`, but will build new one with default error message for this field, like `"Field " + fieldName + " is Invalid"` and put it instead of the one we want.